# How to change wordpress img attributes

Tags: php, html, image

Am using [Unveil plugin](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil) to lazy load images in wordpress. I would like to change the img attributes to something like this.

```
<img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/500/city/10" data-src-retina="http://lorempixel.com/g/1280/800/city/10" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
```

With [this link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/convert-image-base64-php) I was able to achieve `src` now I kindly request someone to help on how to generate `data-src and data-src-retina` attributes.

Later I want to use them in my [function](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-change-img-tag-html/) in funtions.php

Bellow is my code snippet, but its not working only the `src`

```
function image_tag($html, $id, $alt, $title) {
//generate data url
$type = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($img);
$src = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

return preg_replace(array(
        '/'.str_replace('//','//',get_bloginfo('url')).'/i',
        '/s+width="d+"/i',
        '/s+height="d+"/i',
        '/alt=""/i'
    ),
    array(
        'data-src=" "',
        'src="'.$src.'"',
        'data-src-retina=" "',
        'alt="' . $title . '"'
    ),
    $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 0, 4);
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?